# Long format handling while calculating factorial

Tags: c, function, long-integer, factorial

I wrote a code that calculates factorial after creating a myFactorial function however I messed it up when I tried to handle greater numbers.

I am trying to deal with numbers above 16 using long format but the results are irrelevant and things get weirder in the second part of the code. 
While the results should not change with input, they do change!

I share my code with comments below:

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int yourNumber;
    int i;

    //Take the input
    printf("I highly recommend you to make the command window fullscreen. Otherwise, the complete output will not be seen.\n");
    printf("Enter a positive integer and I will tell you its factorial.\n");
    scanf("%d", &yourNumber);

    //Calculate factorial and print it in three ways
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d!\n",yourNumber,myFactorial(yourNumber));
    printf("Using long format, factorial of %d is %lld!\n",yourNumber,myFactorial(yourNumber));
    printf("In hex: %#08X!",myFactorial(yourNumber));




    // Here on, second part of my code begins


    // Calculate and print factorials of numbers from 1 to 20 in %d format
    printf("\n\n\nLet's see more d's!\n\n");
    for (i = 1; i<21; i++)   printf("%d\n", myFactorial(i));

    // Calculate and print factorials of numbers from 1 to 20 in %lld format
    printf("\n\n\nNow let's see more lld's!\n\n");
    for (i = 1; i<21; i++)   printf("%lld\n", myFactorial(i));


    return 0;
}
```

---

myfactorial.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int myFactorial(int bar) {
    long long out = 1;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=bar; i++)
    {
        out *= i;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem that you face?  The factorial output is correct: http://cpp.sh/8twwh

Comment: Hi, using long long will also result in overflow of long range. if you really wanted to learn go through this. 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-large-number/
Or 
https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/7349/computing-factorials-of-a-huge-number-in-cc-a-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You have problems with your `printf` formats:

All `printf` that prints the returned value of myFactorial must use `%lld` format, for `long long int`

`printf` that prints the HEX value must use `%llX` to print the correct value

```
//Calculate factorial and print it in three ways
printf("Factorial of %d is %lld!\n",yourNumber,myFactorial(yourNumber));
printf("Using long format, factorial of %d is %lld!\n",yourNumber,myFactorial(yourNumber));
printf("In hex: %#016llX!",myFactorial(yourNumber));

// Here on, second part of my code begins

// Calculate and print factorials of numbers from 1 to 20 in %d format
printf("\n\n\nLet's see more d's!\n\n");
for (i = 1; i<21; i++)   printf("%lld\n", myFactorial(i));

// Calculate and print factorials of numbers from 1 to 20 in %lld format
printf("\n\n\nNow let's see more lld's!\n\n");
for (i = 1; i<21; i++)   printf("%lld\n", myFactorial(i));
```

You can simply find those kind of error adding `-Wall` option when compile with gcc. It will show you

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:84:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("Factorial of %d is %d!\n",yourNumber,myFactorial(yourNumber));
     ^
test.c:86:5: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("In hex: %#08X!",myFactorial(yourNumber));
     ^
test.c:94:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’ [-Wformat=]
     for (i = 1; i<21; i++)   printf("%d\n", myFactorial(i));
```

Best adding all following option: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

> Take note that your code can work correctly as far as the factorial is less then `9223372036854775807` that is the maximum allowed for `long long int`

That means you can calculate the factorial where `x <= 20`